Starting page numbering after TOC and reflecting in TOC
What I wish for
I want to start page numbering 1 after TOC, i.e., from section 1 page and reflect that page number in TOC. All the pages before section 1 should be ignored in TOC.
What I additionally tried watching similar questions
If I write
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}

after TOC, then the page number starts from 1 but that is not reflecting in TOC.
MWE
\documentclass[12pt] {article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\def\baselinestretch{2.0}
\renewcommand\cftsecaftersnum{.}
\renewcommand\cftsecdotsep{\cftdotsep}
\titleformat{\paragraph}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\setlength{\textwidth}{18cm} 
\setlength{\textheight}{21cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.15cm}
\newcommand{\toright}[1]{%
    \leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\hfill\penalty13 
    \null\nobreak\hskip1em plus1fill\hbox{#1}%
}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.15cm}
\title{\textbf{}}
\author{}
\affil{\textbf{...-}\;...}
\affil{\textbf{... -}\;...}
\date{}
\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
            This is my title page\\
            \huge{\bfseries{XXX}}\\[0.5cm]
            \large{\emph{XXX}}\\[0.5cm]
            \huge{XXX} \\[3cm]
            \large{\textbf{XXX}}\\[1cm]
            \large{\textbf{XXX -}\;XXX}
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
    \clearpage
    \section*{Acknowledgment}
    \begin{justify}
        This is my acknowledgment
    \end{justify}
    \clearpage
    \tableofcontents
    \pagestyle{fancy} \fancyhf{} 
    \fancyhead[LO]{XXX}
    \fancyhead[RE]{XXX}
    \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage} 
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
    \newpage
    \section{section 1}
    \subsection{subsection 1.1}
    \subsection{subsection 1.2}
    \clearpage
    \section{section 2}
\end{document}


Here is a rather minimal example of what you try to achieve:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

  \begin{titlepage}
    \huge This is my title page
  \end{titlepage}
  \pagenumbering{roman}       %%%%% insert this

  \section*{Acknowledgment}
    This is my acknowledgment
  \clearpage
  \tableofcontents
  \clearpage                  %%%%% insert this
  \pagenumbering{arabic}      %%%%% insert this

  \section{section 1}
  \lipsum[2]

  \clearpage
  \section{section 2}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{document}

